# How to automatically switch to home directory when switching user?

Tags: linux, unix, user-accounts, ubuntu-16.04, su

When i ssh to my ubuntu server, i get logged in to my user's home folder.

But when i do `su otheruser` and enter the password, i get logged in as the otheruser but the home directory stays for the previous user.

How to automatically switch to the logged user's home dir?

Answer (score 14):

Try to us `su - otheruser` command which starts the shell as a login shell with an environment similar to a real login:

1. it clears all the environment variables except TERM
2. it initializes the environment variables HOME, SHELL, USER, LOGNAME, and PATH
3. **it changes to the target user's home directory**
4. it sets argv[0] of the shell to '-' in order to make the shell a login shell